# LWC Record View Form: Error: Field [xyz__c] was not found

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

Although I have access to the field and the field is in the layout, I am getting error in Developer Console (Chrome).

> Error: Field [xyz__c] was not found

Code Snippet below:

```
<lightning-record-view-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Case">
    <lightning-output-field field-name="xyz__c">
    </lightning-output-field>
</lightning-record-view-form>
```

What am I missing? If I use some other field, it works fine.

Comment: what type of field is it?

Comment: Along with the type question, does the field comes from a managed package having a namespace?

Comment: no its a custom text field (length limit 255 chars)